# Exchange Online Powershell connect using c#

Tags: c#, powershell, office365

I have been trying to connect to exchange online using Powershell. Here is a code I followed;

```
System.Security.SecureString securePassword = new System.Security.SecureString();
foreach (char c in AdminPass)
{
    securePassword.AppendChar(c);
}

PSCredential credential = new PSCredential(AdminUser, securePassword);
WSManConnectionInfo connectionInfo = new WSManConnectionInfo(new Uri("https://outlook.office365.com/powershell-liveid/"), "http://schemas.microsoft.com/powershell/Microsoft.Exchange", credential);
connectionInfo.AuthenticationMechanism = AuthenticationMechanism.Basic;
connectionInfo.MaximumConnectionRedirectionCount = 2;
using (Runspace runspace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace(connectionInfo))
{
     using (PowerShell powershell = PowerShell.Create())
     {
            runspace.Open(); //Its dying here
            powershell.Runspace = runspace;
            powershell.AddCommand("New-MailContact");
            powershell.AddParameter("Name", DisplayName);
            powershell.AddParameter("ExternalEmailAddress", UPN);
            Collection<PSObject> result = powershell.Invoke();
      }
}
```

As mentioned above, it's throwing error from line: **runspace.Open()**

Here is the error:

> **Connecting to remote server outlook.office365.com failed with the following error message : The parameter is incorrect. For more
> information, see the about_Remote_Troubleshooting Help topic.**

```
Stack Trace:

   at System.Management.Automation.Runspaces.AsyncResult.EndInvoke()
   at System.Management.Automation.Runspaces.Internal.RunspacePoolInternal.EndOpen(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Management.Automation.Runspaces.Internal.RemoteRunspacePoolInternal.Open()
   at System.Management.Automation.RemoteRunspace.Open()
   at AzureAD.Helper.UserManagement.CreateContact(String DisplayName, String MailNickName, String Password, String UPN, String ImmutableId, String AdminUser, String AdminPass, String tenantName) in :line 263
   at AzureAD.Program.<CreateCompleteUsercn>d__3.MoveNext() in
```

Any clues please?

Comment: The code works well for me.

The code works well for me.  
**AzureAD.Program.<CreateCompleteUsercn>d__3.MoveNext() in**
Are you writing the code in a loop? If yes, could the code run successfully at the first time?

Comment: Hey, Ya its a loop. But it never works for me, not even first time..

Answer (score 0):

This code worked for me as well. If the AdminUser or AdminPassword were incorrect, you would get an Access Denied error, so that can't be the issue.  I see this post is a couple years old, and I remember that after this endpoint (outlook.office365.com) was added it didn't work everywhere for a time.  Is this working for you now?  If not, perhaps try the old endpoint https://ps.outlook.com/powershell?

Alternatively, you could use Import-PSSession instead of WSMan to connect.  See [Exchange PowerShell commands through C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10575742/exchange-powershell-commands-through-c-sharp/48527914#48527914) for more information on that.